# Create list using properties in other list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects containing project name and owners of the project something like this:

```
[
    {
        project_name:"abc",
        project_duration:"2 weeks",
        contactInfo: [
          {
            name:"john"
          },
          {
            name:"ron"
          },
        ]
    },
    {
        project_name:"def",
        project_duration:"4 weeks",
        contactInfo: [{
            name:"steve"
        }]
    },
    {
        project_name:"xyz",
        project_duration:"9 weeks",
        contactInfo: [{
            name:"john"
        }]
    }
]
```

How to create a list containing projects for each user from the above list?

```
[
    {
        name: "john",
        projects:[
            {
                project_name:"abc"
            },
            {
                project_name:"xyz"
            }

        ]   
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi chvc, welcome to stackoverflow, please provide your attempt and what issue you are facing

Comment: And please an [mcve] is always a good plan. Because of some typo the response object is weird.

Answer (score 2):

[Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) your object based on the property `Name` value.
Then Select the new object:
- The `Name` is the grouping key.
- The sublist is just a projection from the old object.

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.contactInfo.name)
    .Select(g =>
        new Result
        {
            name = g.Key,
            projects =
                g.Select(x => new Project_t2
                {
                    project_name = x.project_name,
                    projec_name = x.project_duration
                }).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQ4f82)

Comment: Just a note, `projec_name` should be removed from `Project_t2`, as the desired output doesn't contain anything about `project_duration`

Comment: @Ammar, I made comment about it in the live demo and under the question. That's a typo from OP. Here I just ignored it and make it an other property. As it's unclear if Op needs a object list or a Json, the typoed property can be set to ignore. Just like I ignored the filter on `Name=="john"`, because I felt like Op need to see the result of this unfiltered to understand better what is happening. But the filter is in the live demo.

Comment: @xdtTransform `contactInfo` property is array of objects instead of single object something like this: `contactInfo:[{name:"john"},{name:"ron"}]`. I updated the question.